# Changing formula inside summation

Tags: summation, dirac-delta

I probably forgot something about summations but can someone explain to me how do you go from
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(\frac{t}{2}-n)
$$
to
$$
2\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-2n)
$$
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$ you get
$$
\delta(\frac{t}{2}-n)
= \delta(\frac12(t-2n))
= \frac{1}{1/2}\delta(t-2n)
= 2\delta(t-2n).
$$